# Building regex to match 2 words only

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to make regexp that match only 2 words and a single pace between. No special symbols, only `[a-zA-Z]` space `[a-zA-z]`.

```
Foo Bar      # Match    (two words and one space only)
Foo          # Mismatch (only one word)
Foo  Bar     # Mismatch (2 spaces)
Foo Bar Baz  # Mismatch (3 words)
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the regex you wrote so we can correct it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$`

```
^   # Matches the start of the string
+   # quantifier mean one or more of the previous character class 
\s  # matches whitespace characters
$   # Matches the end of the string
```

The anchors `^` and `$` are important here.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/UFbKc1):

```
if "foo bar" =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/ 
    print "match 1"
end 
if "foo  bar" =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/ 
    print "match 2"
end 
if "foo bar biz" =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/ 
    print "match 3"
end
```

Output:

```
Match 1
```

Comment: A shorter way for `[a-zA-Z]` would be: `[A-z]`.

Comment: @Cerbrus, VERY wrong, `[A-z]` is NOT the same as `[a-zA-Z]`. In IRB, try `('A' .. 'z').to_a.grep(/[A-z]/)` vs. `('A' .. 'z').to_a.grep(/[a-zA-Z]/)
`

Comment: @Cerbrus Most regexp supports case insensitivity I could have written `if "foo BAR" =~ /^[a-z]+\s[a-z]+$/i` which uses the `i` flag for this.